# Marking mobile issues as fixed with google

Tags: website-design, mobile, resolution

According to Google Webmaster Tools, It claims I have one mobile usability issue that the tap targets are too close, yet I have fixed it however Google still claims its a problem. See the attached picture:

[image: Error screen]

What I have circled is the date Google claimed to have *last* detected the error as well as the status date. What throws me off more is that the chart still shows one error, however the detection date hasn't been updated. I don't understand why the status date is new and the last detected date is old and the chart shows one error. I think Google is mistaken.

So my question then is what can I do immediately to indicate to Google that mobile issues are 100% fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. This will go away when Google retests the page.

I went through some of this by the thousands. It has been since at least early May that all of the errors have been fixed, and still there is about 125 remaining as of this morning. It takes time of course, however, Google does say it is a priority to retest mobile pages. However, it may be that as you get to the end of your list, Google may slow down. At least that is the way is seems to be for me. I assume this is because of the pages relative importance. You may see that Googles regular spider has visited some of these pages before the mobility test. I experienced this. However, it does appear that the mobility test will occur one or more days after.

Since you have only a few, try submitting them using the Fetch as Google. That spider may not fix the problem, however, it may trigger the mobility test to follow soon after. Who knows for sure?

Incidentally, for what it is worth, while there are different spiders from Google, G admits that they are all the same spider with different intents. The advantage is this. If one of the media or mobility spiders visits your page, it is also the same as the regular spider visiting your page. The converse is also at least somewhat true if not entirely true. While the fetch comes from different places and processed specifically for the portion of the index that requested the fetch, the systems are designed to save bandwidth (both yours and theirs) and conserve requests by advantaging the other processes and indexes as well.

It will all work out okay.

Remember that search engines are notoriously slow.

Comment: Ok, so then why did they offer the "mark as fixed" option for pages that are not found? Is google really that bad?

Comment: @Mike Because most 404's are unintentional. The Mark as Fixed did not always exist.